# determine a set of numbers that divide n

Tags: number-theory

I believe this is a number theory problem.  Could someone point me to any theorems I should look at to start solving this?

Determine all $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $[n/k]$ divides $n$ for $1<k < n$.

Comment: Presumably, by $[n/k]$ you mean the floor function $\lfloor n/k\rfloor$? And also that you mean for all such $k$?

Comment: Hint: choose $a\ge0$ so that $2^a$ is the highest power of $2$ dividing $n$; now consider what happens when $k=2^{a+1}$.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. So in the first situation would n/k=2^a?  Or if that's the numerator then the 2^a cancel out and you're left with 1/2.